# Making sure a list of cosets is exhaustive

Tags: group-theory, algorithms

I have a basic group theory question but I can't seem to find a satisfying answer.

For example, say I'm interested in the subgroup $H$ of $S_5$ generated by the cycle $(1\, 2\,3)$, and I want to list all its *left* cosets (ie all the sets of the form $xH$ with $x \in S_5$).

And I can use a few properties such that $xH = yH \iff xy^{-1} \in H$ to simplify my research (since it states that if two permutations differ by a $(1\,2\,3)^k$ cycle the coset is going to be the same).

But it only makes the listing *barely any* quicker. And when working by hand with relatively big groups like $S_5$, I can't really find a listing method that allows me to say « that's it, the list is complete I don't have to try with **all** the remaining elements ».

Hope I made my question clear enough, thank you guys for reading.

Comment: All cosets of a subgroup have the same cardinality as the  subgoup, hence the number of cosets of $H$ is exactly $|S_5|/|H|$=$120/3=40$.

Comment: I added the [tag:algorithms] tag. I'm  not sure why but it appears to be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$ generates a group $H$ with $3$ elements, there will be $40\left(=\frac{120}3\right)$ cosets. One of them will be $H$, of course.

Now, take $\sigma\in S_5\setminus H$. Say that you take $\sigma=(1\ \ 4)$. Now, compute $\sigma H$. That will give you a second coset.

Then, you take $\eta\in S_5\setminus(H\cup\sigma H)$ (note that $H$ and $\sigma H$ are disjoint) and you start all over again.

After having obtained $40$ cosets, you're done.

Comment: For OP: Built into this, of course, is the fact that different cosets are mutually disjoint.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a better algorithm to list a complete set of representatives for these 40 cosets.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Nice remark. I've added somthing about that to my answer.

Comment: Hi, good point. It sounds loong but it was a helpful answer, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.